# SSL Cert for sub.domain.com and www.sub.domain.com

Tags: tls, certificates, sub-domain

I have a wildcard cert issued by godaddy for *.domain.com.

currently,  https://sub.domain.com  works just fine.  however, https://www.sub.domain.com  does not work. Do I need a separate cert for each?

the error i see in browser when i goto https://www.sub.domain.com is:

```
The identity of this website has not been verified.
 • Server's certificate does not match the URL.
```

Answer (score 4):

A wildcard certificate is a public key certificate which can be used with multiple subdomains of a domain. Depending on the number of subdomains an advantage could be that it saves money and also could be more convenient.

**Note: But Only a single level of subdomain matching is supported**

The workaround could be to add every virtual host name in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) extension, the major problem being that the certificate needs to be reissued whenever a new virtual server is added.

Because the wildcard only covers one level of subdomains (the asterisk doesn't match full stops), these domains would not be valid for the certificate: xxx.sub.domain.com

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard SSL protects the unlimited numbers of subdomains in the terms of all are created on your main domain name.

When Wildcard SSL certificate issued for `*.domain.com`, that can secure…

- sub1.domain.com
- sub1.domain.com
- anything.domain.com

If you want to secure your second level domain names which are hosted under the same sub-domain of your website. You need to issue your certificate for `*.sub.domain.com`, but it counts  `sub.domain.com` as a main domain name and secures…

- sub1.sub.domain.com
- sub2.sub.domain.com
- anything.sub.domain.com

**Note: Wildcard SSL Certificate doesn’t support `any.thing.domain.com`**

Buying an individual certificate for the `domain.com`, `anysub.domain.com` or `any.thing.domain.com`, it can be more costly as well as hard to manage all certificates. You can secure your entire website with single UCC / SAN certificate that the cost can be around $45. (Price from [SSL2BUY](https://www.ssl2buy.com/comodo-multi-domain-ssl.php))

- domain.com
- www.domain.co.uk
- www.domain.tld
- sub1.domain.com
- sub1.sub1.domain.com
- sub2.sub2.domain.com
- any.thing.domain.tld

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a separate entry for sub-sub-domains. A wildcard matches only a single label and there can only a single and only leftmost wildcard in the domain, i.e.

- `*.example.com` matches `sub.example.com`, but not `www.sub.example.com` and not `example.com`
- You can not get `sub.*.example.com`.
- You can not get `*.*.example.com`.
- But `*.sub.example.com` is possible, but does not match `sub.example.com`.

You don't need a separate certificate for all of these. They can be in the same certificate as subject alternative names.

Comment: so my subdomains are 1 for each customer I have.  the list of subdomains is endless. so how can i get ssl for www.X.domain.com and www.Y.domain.com.  do i need a separate entry in the SAN for X,Y,Z?

Comment: Yes, you need separate SAN or separate certificates. Again, there is no `*.*.example.com`.